# Why is there no assumptions about IVs' and DV's distribution in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, distributions, correlation, multivariate-analysis, linear

Many sources say that we do not have to make any assumptions about normality of distribution of IVs and DV. The requirement of normality applies only to the distribution of errors. I wonder why that is true. My doubts appear due to the fact that we use spearman's correlation when calculating betas, and with non-normal data spearman's correlation tends to become not efficient and not robust.

As well, it might be a good idea to calculate correlations between IVs and DV before including IVs into regression model, however we cannot use pearson correlation for that if the data is not normally distributed. It seems strange to run spearman's correlations for that purpose first, and then build multivariate linear regression, which is based on pearson correlation.

Would be very grateful for your help as well as for reference to any literature on the issue.

Comment: Because you refer to "DV" (dependent variable) in the singular throughout your question, it sounds like you are asking about *multiple regression* (one DV, many IVs) rather than *multivariate regression* (multiple DVs). If that's the case, then your question is thoroughly addressed on many threads on this site: please search it.  If it's not the case, then could you please clarify what you are asking about?

Comment: The post contains so many misconceptions (like Spearman's correlation being inefficient under nonnormality; Pearson correlation only possible under normality) that it will be difficult to give a proper answer. There are different assumptions in regression, each being important only for certain aspects of the results (coefficient estimates, their p values, R-squared...). So on what aspects are you focussing?